# Can you reclaim resources from enemy starbases?

Tags: galactic-civilizations-2

I went to war with an enemy race and attacked one of their starbases, which was built on a resource (in this case, an economic resource).

The starbase was easily destroyed, but the resource was gone too.

That obviously is not the result I had in mind, I was hoping to mine the resource myself.

1. Can you destroy a starbase without destroying the underlying resource?
2. If not, is there a way to capture starbases like you capture planets? (i.e. not through influence, but in a faster way)

Comment: Eh? That's news to me... AFAICT, destroying a starbase destroys only the starbase, the resource is still there... what edition of GalCiv2 are you playing?

Comment: Ultimate Edition (Steam) including both DLCs.

Comment: Okay, were you playing the ToA or DA expansion? Or were you playing the 'plain' GC2 (aka the 'DL' mode)?

Comment: As I said, ultimate Edition includes both DA and ToA.

Comment: The three games (DL, DA, and ToA) are actually different executables. And the three 'variants' have slightly different gameplays. In other words, it's "three games in one bundle." That's why I asked, which 'edition'/'variant' are you paying.

Comment: Ultimate Edition, bought and started over Steam. I am by no definition a GalCiv expert. If there are significantly different answers for each version, it would be optimal if an answer could point them out. (I am aware that this might be too much to ask)

Comment: I'd like to answer that, however, TBH, I only had destroyed starbases in DA and DL, haven't tried doing that in ToA, so gameplay _might_ be different. In DA and DL, the resources survive the starbase destruction.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I guess I will have to test it and provide an answer myself then. Pretty sure the Steam Version is ToA. For now it seems that resources get destroyed, unless you know another way to capture them (influence ignored)

Comment: Just to add: I just destroyed a resource starbase in ToA, and yet the resource itself survived the starbase blast. Maybe there's a "survival chance" of the resource? As in, 'x% chance the explosion of the starbase will destroy the resource'.